# Why is it the case that the name of the function f4 has internal linkage, and not a C language linkage?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, linkage

The fifth example in [[dcl.link]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.link#4) states the following:

```
extern "C" {
    static void f4(); // the name of the function f4 has internal linkage (not C language linkage)
                      // and the function’s type has C language linkage.
}
```

Why is this? Why is it the case that the name of the function `f4` has internal linkage, and not a C language linkage?

P.S.: I'm asking this from a perspective of a language-lawyer. That is, how can one derive the commented statement above, from normative paragraphs in the Standard?

Comment: Because it's static (and therefore local to the translation unit)? Can't quote from the standard to support this, though...

Comment: [\[basic.link\]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.link#3).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From that same section, emphasis mine:

> In a linkage-specification, the specified language linkage applies to the function types of all function declarators, function names with **external linkage**, [...]

But, `f4` is declared `static`, which means that name has internal linkage per [[basic.link]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.link#3.1):

> A name having namespace scope has internal linkage if it is the name of:
>
> - a variable, function or function template that is explicitly declared `static`; or, [...]

Hence, the C linkage doesn't apply.